Can you hear "pictures"


Listen to the conversations and number the pictures in the order you hear them.


Sentence one is what I hear in a listening test.  But I find this sentence needs a little modification, because you can't hear pictures("them").
Explanation:
Pictures are not directly mentioned in the conversations. The test takers hear the conversation and infer the identities of the speakers and the scenario. One picture illustrates a scenario.

You match the image to the conversation you hear. For example there are three conversations in three different situations and three different images/photos/pictures: (hotel) a guest and a receptionist, (restaurant) a customer and a waiter, and (inside a car) a driver and passenger.

@Mari-LouA So do you think the original sentence is a good one and needs no modification?

It can be made clearer i.e. match the pictures to the conversations you hear,  but the original text doesn't need to be modified. It is fine because we know that pictures are not audible.

Part of your confusion results from the ambiguity of them in the sentence:

Listen to the conversations and number the pictures in the order you hear them.

At first glance, them can refer either to pictures or to conversations. But as you say, it's hard to imagine hearing a picture. So we need to interpret what we are hearing; this will lead us to understand that we are hearing various conversations. As we hear the set of conversations, we are asked to match them to a second set, this time a set of pictures that we can see.
For example, imagine these groups of people having conversations:

A doctor and a patient.
Two football players.
A teacher and a student.

Now imagine a set of pictures:
A. A football.
B. A hospital bed.
C. A blackboard.
The matching would then be 1B, 2A, and 3C.

So do you think the original sentence is a good one and needs no modification?

Well that's hard for me to answer, because I'm not doing the test. But it makes sense to me; I understand the intended meaning. Sentences can always be rewritten. If you have a problem, it would be better for you to propose an alternative.
